# URLDownloadToFile halts if limited bandwidth in VB 6.0

Tags: winapi, vb6

I am using URLDownloadToFile to download files from internet in VB 6.0.

The issue is that if I restrict my bandwidth of network, my application halts when I start downloading.

I am using callbacks to check the progress of download and timeout, but when my application halts my callback methods even not fire.

I also used VB timer to check the progress of download but this timer also not fired if my application is in halt state.

I want to abort the downloading if the server is not responding, kindly suggest me any solution to solve this.

**EDIT**

I have resolved this issue using [AsyncRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277589.aspx) in VB, AsyncRead is natively available in VB and can resolved these kind of issue, Following link may help you.

http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2008/03/27/simple-asynchronous-downloads.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB 6 does not support multithreading; VB 6 apartment threaded objects and programs are limited to execution in an STA (Single Threaded Apartment). This means that your exe can spin up as many threads as it wants, but only one thread in the apartment can execute at a time (no concurrent execution).

You can create VB.Net wrapper COM visible class and make file download in separate thread.